# When using View Code on a XOML file, designer view is displayed

Tags: visual-studio, designer, designview, code-view

In Visual Studio:
When you right-click on a xoml file in the solution explorer and select "View Code" it takes you to the designer (design view).

**Steps to Reproduce**

- create a xoml
- add something into the code-behind [I used C#]
- Close the code-behind and designer
- right-click the xoml from the Solution Explorer
- Select "View Code"

**Actual Results**

- Designer view is opened.

**Expected Results**

- Code view should open.

Answer (score 1):

I found this question elsewhere, unanswered, so here's the solution/workaround I discovered.

- right-click on a xoml file in Solution Explorer.
- select "Open With..."
- select "Xml Editor"
- click "Set as Default"
- click "OK"

You should now be able to view the code.

NOTE:
Different settings for the default opener have odly (stupidly?) different behaviors. On my VS2008 with .NET 3.5 SP1:
**Workflow Designer:** only allows designer view.
**XML Editor:** only allows code view.
**Source Code (Text) Editor:** defaults to designer view, but allows code view.